# Speed up a infinity series

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

Is there any trick to speed up the plotting of my function `u[x,t]`?

```
u2 = 3;
u1 = 2;
u0 = 1;

u[x_, t_] := 
 Chop[(u2 - u1)/l x + u1 + 
   NSum[2/(n \[Pi]) ((u2 - u1) (-1)^
     n - (u0 - u1) ((-1)^n - 1)) Exp[-((n^2 \[Pi]^2 a^2)/l^2)
     t] Sin[(n \[Pi] x)/l], {n, 1, Infinity}]]


Plot3D[u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
(* no result when 2 hours later *)
```

In addition, I notice that it does not work even when I replace `Infinity` with 30.

Comment: Please note that there are  unknow parameters  `l` and `a` in you code.

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry for the missing parameter, `l` and `a` can be assigned any positive real number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is:

```
u2 = 3;
u1 = 2;
u0 = 1;
l = 1;(*I'm assumed*)
a = 1/2;(*I'm assumed*)
inf = 100;(*I'm assumed*)

u[x_, t_] = (u2 - u1)/l x + u1 + Sum[2/(n \[Pi]) ((u2 - u1) (-1)^
    n - (u0 - u1) ((-1)^n - 1)) Exp[-((n^2 \[Pi]^2 a^2)/
     l^2) t] Sin[(n \[Pi] x)/l], {n, 1, inf}];

Plot3D[u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Note the key difference here is [Set](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) `=` vs [SetDelayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) `:=`. In essence, in Mariusz' example you calculate the serious only once, whereas in your the other case you calculate it for every plot point.